# Navbar bg to overflow to section below (updated)

Tags: css, stackoverflow

This might be an unusual question. But is there any css for making the navbar background to overflow to the next section below? We want to create a seamless interaction with the graphical id of the hole site between the navbar and the rest of the website.

Url to website: https://labified.se/19-2/

This is the code we got so far. We have tried with different codes but nothing really get us on the right track.

```
#main-header {
Background-size: cover;
Background-repeat: no-repeate;
Background-image: url;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are going to need to show some examples, no-one can help you with your question until they can see it working or at least see code examples to offer suggestions.

Comment: https://labified.se/19-2/

Comment: That does not help - you need to show the code here, make it easy for people to help you.